# How to uniquely select month in sql using date records?

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

I have a problem with my current system. I have a table named `Payment` on my database.
This is the picture of the table

[image]

As you can see, I have the same details of Interest Balance for the month of March and April.
But I wanted the `resultset`value to be like this:

[image]

I just want only one `currentIntBal` details for each month. By the way, I also need to know how to convert the `varchar` of date to date datatype itself because the field `lastPaymentDate` is in `varchar` datatype
How could I possibly do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
with monthlyPayments as
(
  select *
    , rownum = row_number() over (partition by year(lastPaymentDate), month(lastPaymentDate) order by lastPaymentDate)
  from payments
)
select lastPaymentDate
  , currentIntBal
from monthlyPayments
where rownum = 1
```

[SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c8a99/2).

In this case I'm just taking the first payment for each month.

**Edit after additional information:**

```
with monthlyPayments as
(
  select *
    , rownum = row_number() over (partition by year(convertedDate), month(convertedDate) order by convertedDate)
  from payments p
    cross apply (select convertedDate = cast(replace(lastPaymentDate,'-','') as date)) c
)
select lastPaymentDate = convertedDate
  , currentIntBal
from monthlyPayments
where rownum = 1
```

In the new query above I've changed *lastPaymentDate* from `varchar` to `date`. I used a `CROSS APPLY` so it could be referenced multiple times without repeating code.

Note that I've also changed the date format to an ISO format to prevent any issues with different connection languages - `YYYY-MM-DD` can give inconsistent results but `YYYYMMDD` will be consistent.

[SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a8f69/2).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
SELECT MIN(lastPaymentDate) As lastPaymentDate, currentInBal
FROM   yourTable
GROUP BY currentInBal, MONTH(lastPaymentDate)+12*YEAR(lastPaymentDate)
```

Another slightly different way:

```
SELECT MIN(lastPaymentDate) As lastPaymentDate, 
    MIN(currentInBal) As currentInBal
FROM   yourTable
GROUP BY MONTH(lastPaymentDate)+12*YEAR(lastPaymentDate)
```

Comment: Sir, can you explain what is this line `GROUP BY MONTH(lastPaymentDate)+12*YEAR(lastPaymentDate)` for? thank you

Comment: It creates a unique Month Number, so that every date in that month has the same number, but every date in another month has a different month number.  It basically allows grouping by months from DATETIME values